# Why open files limits set correctly on dedicated server but not on KVM machines?

Tags: debian, virtual-machines, dedicated-server, ulimit

I have set open files for all users on a dedicated server A in `/etc/security/limits.conf` like below:

```
*     hard   nofile  1048576
*     soft   nofile  983040
```

And in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` I have loaded limits module like below:

```
session   required   pam_limits.so
```

I restarted server A and checking `ulimit -Sn` (soft limits) and `ulimit -Hn` (hard limits) displays the newly set values.

Now I have another dedicated server B in which I have 3 KVM machines. On the dedicated server B itself I have set open file as above and it works like a charm after a reboot. The same procedure for server's VMs fails and it shows default open files.

**NOTE:** They all have Debian OS

Is there something here I'm missing? Is it related to VMs at all? How should I set open files for VMs?